# Referencing element attributes from generated li in Angular4

Tags: html, angular

I have a simple todo list generated with `*ngFor`, and I'm trying to get the `li`'s `offsetTop` value. I can do this just fine for the first generated li, but I need to be able to set a variable to any of the li's and their attributes. Is there some form of indexing I can use with template variables to achieve a "this" effect?

My template:

```
<li class="search-item" #todoli
  *ngFor="let todoItem of todos; let item=index "
  (click)="selectTodo($event, todoItem)"
>
  <span class="todo-item">{{ todoItem.name }}</span>
  <span class="delet-todo" (click)="deleteTodo(item)">&#10005;</span>
</li>
```

My component TS (Shortened to the code that uses the @ViewChild target):

```
  li: any;

  @ViewChild("todoli") 
    todoli;

  selectTodo(event, i) {
    this.selectedItem = i;
    this.li = this.todoli.nativeElement;
    console.log(this.li.offsetTop);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do it without any `ViewChild/ViewChildren` references:

```
<li class="search-item" #todoli
  *ngFor="let todoItem of todos; let item=index "
  (click)="selectTodo($event, todoItem, todoli)"
>


selectTodo(event, i, todoli) {
  this.selectedItem = i;
  this.li = todoli;
  console.log(this.li.offsetTop);
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e3ugae?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

or event without template reference variable through `event.target/currentTarget`

```
<li class="search-item"
  *ngFor="let todoItem of todos; let item=index "
  (click)="selectTodo($event, todoItem)"
>


selectTodo(event, i) {
  this.selectedItem = i;
  this.li = event.target;
  console.log(this.li.offsetTop);
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n2eyd6?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: I almost gave up on Angular today trying to find out how to reference elements. Thank you for not only answering my question, but for showing me the most simple way to get what I need! I will read up on $event now, it seems to be the pice I've been missing.

Answer (score 2):

`ViewChild` is supposed to query a single child. [`ViewChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) should be used to query multiple children:

```
 @ViewChildren("todoli") 
    todolis: QueryList<any>;
```

Where `todoli` is template variable name, and `todolis` is [`QueryList`](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList) object.

Comment: @BenediktSchmidt Why do you offer using private field?

Comment: Because I tried to use the ViewChildren in my own project to check if this works and as I printed the   list I saw that the field was holding the array. I'm not sure if this a bad practice though, I just thought it works so why not

Comment: @BenediktSchmidt It's supposed to be accessed with toArray() or traversed with other QueryList methods

Comment: Oh ok then I take back my comment, sorry